# How to build the rpm package with SHA-256 checksum for files?

Tags: redhat, rpm, docker, rpmbuild

In standard alone RHEL 6.4 rpm build environment, the rpm packages is generated with SHA-256 check sum, which is gotten by command `rpm -qp --dump xxx.rpm`

```
[user@redhat64 abc]$ rpm -qp --dump package/rpm/abc-1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm
..
/opt/company/abc/abc/1.0.1-1/bin/start.sh 507 1398338016 d8820685b6446ee36a85cc1f7387d14537d6f8bf5ce4c5a4ccd2f70e9066c859 0100750 user abcc 0
..
```

While if it is build in `docker` environment (still RHEL6.4) the checksum is md5

```
[user@c1cbdf51d189 abc]$ rpm -qp --dump package/rpm/abc-1.0.1-1.x86_64.rpm
..
/opt/company/abc/abc/1.0.1-1/bin/start.sh 507 1401952578 f229759944ba77c3c8ba2982c55bbe70 0100750 user abcc 0
..
```

If I checked the real file, the file is the same

```
[user@c1cbdf51d189 1.0.1-1]$ sha256sum bin/start.sh
d8820685b6446ee36a85cc1f7387d14537d6f8bf5ce4c5a4ccd2f70e9066c859  bin/start.sh
[user@c1cbdf51d189 1.0.1-1]$ md5sum bin/start.sh
f229759944ba77c3c8ba2982c55bbe70  bin/start.sh
```

How I configure `rpmbuild` to let generated rpm file is SHA-256 based ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not related with docker, it can be enabled by follow configuration

```
echo "%_binary_filedigest_algorithm  8" >> $HOME/.rpmmacros
```

The reason for it is ok in standard alone RHEL 6.4 is because it has the `redhat-rpm-config` packages.

```
bash-4.1# yum install redhat-rpm-config
```

In the package, this configuration exists in `/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/macros`

```
bash-4.1# grep digest /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/macros
%_source_filedigest_algorithm 8
%_binary_filedigest_algorithm 8
```

You can use command `rpmbuild --showrc` to check all the configuration.