# rpm's --dump is not returning the same md5sum

Tags: rpm, md5sum

The rpm man page says the --dump option returns "MD5 checksum of the file's contents, all 128 bits of it."   Yet an md5sum of the same file returns a different sum.

```
# rpm -qf /bin/gawk 
gawk-3.1.7-10.el6.x86_64
# rpm -ql --dump gawk-3.1.7-10.el6.x86_64  | grep "^/bin/gawk"
/bin/gawk 375360 1344351835 6b8a70fd01ae6945219f6720d91fad2f31c932e1f8c49decb3c26362fcdf5e96 0100755 root root 0 0 0 X
# md5sum /bin/gawk
030eaa98ed8d878e27944d0a725eb3b0  /bin/gawk
```

Am I missing an option in my rpm or md5sum command?  Or are there two different md5sum algorithims being used?  This is being run on CentOS:

```
# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
Release:    6.6
Codename:   Final
```

Comment: MD5 *is* MD5. It might be applied over different data. In any case the rpm/grep'ed output value is far to big to big an MD5 value.

Comment: FWIW, http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html shows a valid MD5 value in the example output. Is the local rpm command using SHA-256 or something? (The output length in the question is 256 bits, not the expected 128 bits from an MD5.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062375/how-to-build-the-rpm-package-with-sha-256-checksum-for-files - apparently the documentation is dated, as this answer indicates: "In standard alone RHEL 6.4 rpm build environment, the rpm packages *is generated with SHA-256 check sum*". And the output varies by environment.. but at least the 'problem' has a logical solution. Use an SHA-256 hash generator (ie. [sha256sum](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sha256sum), not md5sum) to view the same value..